# Has anyone been able to use web images with the Tiles and Badges App sample?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I've been trying to get my app's tile to display an image from the web, but couldn't get it to work. I then tried the [Tiles and Badges app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148), where in scenario 3 you can send a tile notification that uses a web image. No matter which image url I paste in the text box, the tile refuses to get updated. So apparently, the sample isn't working either, or something is very wrong.

The images are all smaller than 1024x1024 and less than 200KB. Fun fact: if I download one of the images I unsuccesfully tried to feed the sample, add it to the project and then send a notification using it as a local image, the tile gets updated. So apparently the image isn't the problem.

Has anybody been able to get this working? I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: just tried both the C# and the JS sample and they are working with my image here http://jimoneil.blob.core.windows.net/tiles/stock.jpg (which is publically accessible). Be sure to double-check notification settings aren't turned off in Settings... I presume other apps are updating tiles ok?

Answer (score 0):

Do have internet permission ticket in app manifest? Maybe only your app dont have permission to  download your image from web.